# Coding information from an array in php into a document

Tags: php

I am trying to display the details for the inner array below but don't know how. I manage to get the right answer but with a warning saying array to string conversion how do I avoid the warning along with the answer:

```
      $user = array(

     'name' => 'Joe Blogs',
     'age'  => 25,
     'validate' => 'true',
     'children' => array(
     'Jack',
     'Jill',
     'Mark'

      )
      );
      foreach($user as  $v){

      echo $v . ' ' ."<br />";
      }

      foreach($user['children'] as $h){
      echo "$h ";
      }
```

Comment: Get rid of all these comments. Question stands at being flagged for being too chatty. @jeremyjjbrown

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop will still try to echo the value of `$user['children']`, but arrays can't simply be echoed.... prevent the original loop from trying to display the child array, and leave that to your second loop

```
  foreach($user as  $v){
      if (!is_array($v) {
          echo $v . ' ' ."<br />";
      }
  }
```

or

```
  foreach($user as $key => $v){
      if ($key !== 'children') {
          echo $v . ' ' ."<br />";
      }
  }
```